# Some doubts related about how work a meaning predicate that interprets the parse tree of a DCG grammar in Prolog

Tags: prolog, dcg

I am studying Prolog **DCG grammar* and **parse tree** on the Ivan Bratko book: "Programming for Artificial Intelligence"

I am finding some difficulties with the following example that provide a DCG grammar that create a parse tree from a string that belong to the defined language.

The defined language is a list of moves of a robotic arm that can be only of two type: **up** and **down** so **[up,up,down,up,up]** belongs to the language defined by my DCG grammar.

The program provide also a **meaning/2** predicate that **interprets the parse tree associated with a certain string** and that **mean the distance crossed by robot arm** (Whereas it is associated with a move up the value +1, and the value -1 to a move down)

So for example for the list **[up,up,down,up,up]**, the **mean/2** predicate calculate a +3 distance

This is the code of my example (work well):

```
move(move(Step)) --> step(Step).
move(move(Step, Move)) --> step(Step), move(Move).

step(step(up)) --> [up].
step(step(down)) --> [down].

/* Take the parse tree of a string that belong to the language defined by the DCC grammar and
   calculate the total distance whereas that an up move give a +1 distance and a down move
   give -1 distance
*/
meaning(move(Step, Move), Dist):- 
                                  /* Calculate the distance given by the current step node 
                                     (which can be +1 or -1) */
                  meaning(Step, D1),
                  /* Calculate the distance given by the current moove node
                                     (which must be calculated recursively on a subtree having 
                                      a moove node as root */
                  meaning(Move, D2),
                  /* The final distance series of moves is the distance of the
                                     current step + the distance diven from the moves in the
                                     moove subtree */
                  Dist is (D1 + D2).

meaning(step(Step), Dist):- meaning(Step, Dist).
meaning(move(Step), Dist):- meaning(Step, Dist).

% step(up) means that the distance is +1
meaning(step(up), 1).

% step(down) means that the distance is -1
meaning(step(down), -1).
```

So I have the **meaning/2** predicate that take a parse tree and calculate the total distance of the moves.

So I have 2 **BASE CASE** that rappresent the distance value associated to a single move (to a step), that can be +1 for the up step and -1 for the down step:

```
meaning(step(up), 1).
meaning(step(down), -1).
```

The **meaning/2** take a parse tree that, as defined by the DCG grammar, have a **move** node as root: this root will have a left child that is a **step** node (so it is a single move, so it have a specific distance +1 or -1 associated to it) and a right child that is a **move** node (so it rappresent another subtree)

So the total distance is the sum of the distance of the current step that is +1 or -1 (the left child of the current **move** root) + the distance in right subtree.

I think that this is correct and this is pretty clear for me

The thing that I don't understand is what represent to me these two predicates in the code:

```
meaning(step(Step), Dist):- meaning(Step, Dist).
meaning(move(Step), Dist):- meaning(Step, Dist).
```

I can not stick them in my reasoning :-(

Comment: Was it really necessary to copy the entire question and book section for help on those four lines of code? Also, did you try just _running_ the code? It's obvious what those rules do: they let you call `meaning/2` on wrapped facts directly from the DCG. They simply unwrap the extra struct layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use these rules like so,

```
4 ?- phrase(move(X), [up,up,down,up,up]).
X = move(step(up), move(step(up), move(step(down), move(step(up), 
      move(step(up)))))) ;
false.

5 ?- meaning($X,N).
N = 3 ;
false.
```

The term produced is highly nested:

```
move(step(up),                           % move/2: step/1 , 
     move(step(up),                      %   move/2: step/1 ,
          move(step(down),               %     move/2: step/1 ,
               move(step(up),            %       move/2: step/1 ,
                    move(step(up))))))   %         move/1: step/1 .
```

The code that you ask about, strips away the [*functors*](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=functor%2F3) from the compound terms, getting to the "meat" of it, i.e. `up` or `down` atom [*arguments*](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=arg/3):

**(2)** `meaning(step(Step), Dist):- meaning(Step, Dist).`

*"to find the ''meaning'' of a unary compound term `step(X)`, is the same as to find the ''meaning'' of `X`"*.

**(3)** `meaning(move(Step), Dist):- meaning(Step, Dist).`

*"to find the ''meaning'' of a unary compound term `move(X)`, is the same as to find the ''meaning'' of `X`"*.

**(4)** base cases: ''meaning'' is given as `1` or `-1` for `up` or `down` atoms.

```
meaning(step(up), 1).                    % clashes with rule (2)
meaning(step(down), -1).                 % clashes with rule (2)
```

**(1)** And the main case deals with binary compound terms with the functor `move`:

```
meaning(move(Step, Move), Dist):- 
    meaning(Step, D1),
    meaning(Move, D2),
    Dist is (D1 + D2).
```

`move/2` is a custom version of (non-empty) list, `'.'/2`, actually:

```
1 ?- write_canonical([1,2,3]).
'.'(1,'.'(2,'.'(3,[])))
true.

2 ?- write_canonical([step(up),step(down),step(up)]).
'.'(step(up),'.'(step(down),'.'(step(up),[])))
true.
```

And `meaning/2` is a [*fold*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29).

Comment: I apologize, if sometimes I put long question but otherwise I'm afraid of not being clear in the questions

Comment: @AndreaNobili you've come along nicely, start believing your abilities more and *paraphrase* and *summarize*; even more so, let Prolog code speak for itself mode. :)